# Traversing through a C++ container - what's the fastest way?

Tags: c++, iterator, const-iterator

```
vector<int> my_vector(10);

// A
for (size_t i = 0; i < my_vector.size(); i++) {
    // Do stuff with my_vector[i]       
}

//B
for (vector<int>::iterator it = my_vector.begin(); it != my_vector.end(); it++) {
    // Do stuff with (*it)      
}

//C
for (vector<int>::const_iterator it = my_vector.begin(); it != my_vector.end(); it++) {
    // Do stuff with (*it)      
}
```

Please answer the following questions:

1) If the stuff I do inside the loop changes the value of my_vector elements, is it more efficient to use B over A? Here efficiency = faster traversal. If yes, why?

2) If the elements of my_vector are not modified, what is the fastest way out of three?

Comment: As Andrei Alexandrescu would put it, when it comes down to performance and speed... "I should measure this".

Comment: Is your program not meeting your performance requirements? Have you profiled and traced the bottleneck to this spot?

Comment: They all have the same complexity. That's as much as we can say.

Comment: I don't see that the question fits your code or vice versa. It is all serial so go forth and benchmark on the target hardware. Complexity wise this is equal.

Comment: I didn't measure anything. There is no performance issue. It's just a theoretical question. I am interested whether the constness of the iterator adds some overhead or on the contrary speeds up the traversal.

Comment: The first thing you should do is measure it. But use pre-increment for the iterators.

Comment: @user3334441 _'It's just a theoretical question'_ So asking theoretical questions about such point (performance) is a silly thing. It certainly **all** depends on the target platform (toolchain & OS) you're working for.

Comment: @juanchopanza Pre- vs. post- increment will generally lead to the same code when used in this manner. Please do not contribute to misinformation surrounding the false importance of these types of micro-optimizations.

Comment: @JasonC I have simply adopted it for being _good style_, not by means of micro-optimization: If I don't need a copy, I don't need one!

Comment: @JasonC Do you have proof? It isn't trivial for the compiler to optimize this. There is certainly absolutely zero benefit from using post-increment, so it is simply a pessimization.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, I have proof; look at the generated assembly with optimizations on. The increment operators are all templates with their code available at the point of usage during compilation. The compiler will see what is used, what isn't used, and what side effects are inconsequential, and will optimize the generation of the temporary away accordingly. (They are also able to recognize that you are accessing data sequentially.) Rather than wasting my time explaining it, refer to the literally 1000's of questions about this available on this site and elsewhere, or, even better, try it.

Comment: @JasonC I have no need to try it. I am not in the habit of using premature pessimizations. I see no benefit in using post-increment here, so this is not even an issue for me. Nor should it be for anyone. And I don't have access to more than two compilers right now, so anything I did find would not be general enough.

Comment: @juanchopanza You've missed the point entirely. It's not about pre vs post increment. My criticism is about you blatantly contributing to a programming culture that freaks out about micro-optimizations without having any real knowledge of what is behind it.

Comment: @JasonC There is no micro-optimization here. Just a suggestion to avoid a permature pessimization. Post increment can be as fast as pre-increment in the best case. That leaves me with zero reasons to use it in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Modern compilers are smart enough to optimize all three equally. You can always measure them or look at the generated assembly.

One benefit of the generic iterator approach is that you can use the same code for best-time forward sequential iteration no matter what container type you are using (e.g. you could drop in a `list` or a `set` instead of a `vector`). This may or may not be useful for your situation.

If you are having issues with your application not meeting your performance requirements and you have profiled and concretely identified this as your bottleneck, first consider alternate higher level algorithms, then concentrate on micro-optimizing this spot.

The more important question is: Which of these three produces the clearest, most readable, and most maintainable code?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of typing, none of the above is the answer:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), func);
```

Where `func` is either a functor, standalone function, or a lambda function.

In terms of the code generated by the compiler - 95% of the time, there will not be (much of) a difference between any of the 3 options.  The slight exception being the indexed version - in unoptimized builds, this may call `v.size()` each iteration.  However, with optimizations turned on, they all should be basically identical.  In terms of determining performance, profiling and testing is the key.  You **must** find your real bottlenecks before you can think about trying to optimize things.  Without profiling the application, you are likely to be optimizing something that is either rarely called, or is not your bottleneck.

The real key comes down to writing readable code - and using hand written loops is usually avoided in favor of the appropriate algorithm implementation.

Comment: Also with C++11: `for (auto i : v) { /* do stuff with i */ }`.

Comment: @Snps Perhaps it is just me being an old guy, but I still prefer `for_each` instead of the ranged `for` syntax, but to each their own.

Comment: @Snps Also if you're using Qt, it's got a nice `foreach` macro that works with STL containers (`foreach (int i, v) { /* do stuff */ }`).

Comment: @ZacHowland Both are useful. If it comes down to a single function call on each iteration, then I might use `std::for_each`. But if I need to execute multiple statements then I prefer a range-based for loop instead of e.g. declaring a lambda expression.

Comment: @Snps Like I said, to each their own.  When the C++11 standard included the ranged-based `for` syntax, my reaction was "eh".  I didn't think it was needed since we already had `std::for_each` - which does the same thing.  And don't get me started on `auto` ... :-P

Comment: @ZacHowland I've got your back re: `auto` here, buddy. At least they gave us `override` and `final`. Originally they weren't in there in the draft; I very clearly remember ranting about it in the newsgroup.

Comment: @JasonC Off topic, but I'm still hoping they will put `std::optional` back in the C++14 draft ... I fail to understand their reasons for removing it.

Comment: @ZacHowland As far as I know, it was postponed because enhancement requests and issues were raised that could not be dealt with in a timely manner. I know that is unsatisfying; but I missed out on that conversation and I have searched for rationale before without finding anything. I made a request for information and will let you know if I receive a response.